# Computed property does not get the data correctly Vue.js ,

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Hey i am having a problem with my computed property.

First and foremost i am getting data from my ruby on rails API   , it is going well , now i am filtering that data based on their id,  i do it in my computed property , but if i console log it it just gives me undefined  i cannot access for example the `filteredRecords[0].id` because it is just empty, **however**, i can loop through that array and its giving me correct data. I think it has to do with timing, i am getting the data in my `created(){}` section the filtering is running as well but i just cannot access the data from it directly , that's when i need your help.

Here is how my code looks  right now   ( i am highlighting the important stuff with arrow):

```
<template>
  <body>
    <div
      class="container uppercase text-xl font-mono pl-4 font-semibold no-underline text-indigo-dark hover:text-indigo-darker "
    >
      <table>
        
        <tbody>
          <tr class="priority-200 ">
            <td id="writeDay" class="default ">{{ createdDate }}</td>
            <td id="hour" class="default pl-16">
              {{ createdHours }}
            </td>
            <td
             
              id="degree"
              class="defaulted  white--text
            "
              v-show="filteredDatas && filteredDatas[0].temperature"
            >
              {{ filteredDatas[0].temperature }} °C
            </td>
            <td
              
              id="speed"
              class="defaulted"
              v-show="filteredDatas && filteredDatas[0].windspeed"
            >
              {{ filteredDatas[0].windspeed }} km/h
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
-----------------------------------------------------THIS H1, i can loop through my records without problem-----------------------------------------
      <h1
        v-for="(record, index) of filteredRecords"
        :key="index"
        :record="record"
      >
        <div :class="getClass(record)">
          <strong
            v-show="
              record.path === 'rightoleft' &&
                currentlyActive &&
                record.id == currentlyActive.id
            "
            >{{ record.description }}
          </strong>
         
        </div>
      </h1>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    </div>
  </body>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import moment from "moment";
export default {
  name: "Table",
  data() {
    return {
      templates: [],
      records: [],
      activeSpan: 0,
      datas: [],
      currentlyActive: null,
    
     
     
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    
    this.start();
    
 
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      id: "id",
      dataId: "dataId"
    }),

    createdDate() {
      return moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY ");
    },
    createdHours() {
      return moment().format("HH:mm ");
    },
-----------------------------------------------THATS HOW I FILTER THROUGH MY RECORDS ARRAY WHAT WAS GIVEN FROM AN API

    filteredRecords: function() {
      let localId = this.id;
      let filtered = this.records.filter(record => {
        return record.template_id == localId;
      });
   
      console.log(filtered);
    
      this.anyad = filtered;
      return filtered;
    },

--------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  filteredDatas: function() {
      let localId2 = this.dataId;
      let filtered2 = this.datas.filter(data => {
        return data.id == localId2;
      });
   
      return filtered2;
    }
  },
  methods: {


 
    getClass(record) {
      return {
        rightoleft: record.path === "rightToleft",
       
      };
    },
         ------------------------------------------------------
    start() {
    
      this.currentlyActive = this.filteredRecords[0];    -----> I CANNOT GET THIS ONE ITS GIVING ME NOTHING HELP ------------------------------
      if (!this.currentlyActive) return;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.nextRecord();
      }, this.currentlyActive.time * 1000);
    },
    nextRecord() {
      let currIndex = this.filteredRecords.findIndex(
        f => f === this.currentlyActive
      );
      if (currIndex === this.filteredRecords.length - 1) {
    
        this.currentlyActive = this.filteredRecords[0];
      } else {
        this.currentlyActive = this.filteredRecords[currIndex + 1];
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.nextRecord();
      }, this.currentlyActive.time * 1000);
    }
     ----------------------------------------------------------------
  },

  created() {
  
    if (!localStorage.signedIn) {
      this.$router.replace("/");
    } else {
      this.$http.secured
        .get("/api/v1/records")
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.records.splice(0, this.records.length - 1, ...response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, "Something went wrong"));
      this.$http.secured
        .get("/api/v1/templates")
        .then(response => {
          this.templates = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, "Something went wrong"));
      this.$http.secured
        .get("/api/v1/data")
        .then(response => {
          this.datas = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, "Something went wrong"));
    }
  }

};
</script>


 <style>

.rightoleft {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: yellow;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  animation: move 20s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(50px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(800px);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  92% {
    transform: translate(800px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  94% {
    transform: translate(800px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate(800px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    transform: translate(800px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* 60% {
    transform: translate(500px);
    opacity: 1;
  } */

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(50px);
  }
}
</style>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-sun-sm8tl?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Thats **exactly** how i want to output  like its on sandbox ,on sandbox its working because i am giving it manually the records so it can find for example the filteredRecords[0].id

Can you help me please with that?? what should i do ? Should i copy this thing to another array? if so how do i do that, because the v-for works but accessing it doesnt .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mounted hook that data is not available yet because that data is got in asynchronous way, to deal with this behavior i suggest to use watch property instead of mounted hook:

```
watch:{
  filteredRecords:{
    handler(newVal,oldVal){
    if(newVal.length>0 && newVal.length!==oldVal.length){
      this.start()
     }
   },
  deep:true

  }
}
```

Comment: hello can you explain me does the newVal ,oldVal  mean like the only thing should i do is to just remove my mounted a replace a watch property instead of that?   because i do not understand that handler thing with that two values.

Comment: sorry, i assumed that you know that property and its role please check [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for more details, the handler is the function that provide the new value and the old value of the observed property, the deep field is used when we watch an object or an array